# Filter elements between certain patterns r

Tags: r, list

I have a list for which a small reproducible version is provided below:

```r
mainList <- list("Number 1:",
                 "Initial splits:",
                 "silk",
                 "cotton",
                 "polyester",
                 "Conjugate splits:",
                 "silk",
                 "polyamid",
                 "Number 2:",
                 "Initial splits:",
                 "wool",
                 "cotton",
                 "Conjugate splits:",
                 "nylon",
                 "Number 3:",
                 "Initial splits:",
                 "silk",
                 "polyamid",
                 "wool",
                 "cotton",
                 "Conjugate splits:",
                 "polyester",
                 "wool")
```

The list has 3 components: `Number`,`"Initial splits:"` and `"Conjugate splits:"`. These are always in this order, but the original list is much longer, so filtering manually is not preferred. I am trying to only take the elements that represent the `Number` and the elements under `"Conjugate splits:"` for that `Number`. For example for `"Number 1:"` there are 2 elements under `"Conjugate splits:"`: `silk` and `polyamid`. The number and the 2 elements should be filtered for `"Number 1:"`. The expected output is:

```
expectedList <- list("Number 1:",
                 "silk",
                 "polyamid",
                 "Number 2:",
                 "nylon",
                 "Number 3:",
                 "polyester",
                 "wool")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
out <- by(unlist(mainList),
          cumsum(grepl(":", unlist(mainList))),
          function(x) {
            if (grepl("Number.*:", x[1])) x[1] else {
              if (grepl("Conjugate.*:", x[1])) x[-1]
            }
          })

as.list(do.call(c, unname(out)))
# [[1]]
# [1] "Number 1:"
# [[2]]
# [1] "silk"
# [[3]]
# [1] "polyamid"
# [[4]]
# [1] "Number 2:"
# [[5]]
# [1] "nylon"
# [[6]]
# [1] "Number 3:"
# [[7]]
# [1] "polyester"
# [[8]]
# [1] "wool"
```

Walk-through:

- First, we find and group the elements based on those with colons:

  ```r
  cumsum(grepl(":", unlist(mainList)))
  #  [1] 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 5 6 6 7 8 8 8 8 8 9 9 9
  ```

  If you look at those, you'll see that the `1` is a Number, and the `2`s start with "Initial splits:" (which we don't need), etc.
- We split (`by`) the list by these groups, and determine if we want to keep the *first* of the group (if `Number.*:`), all but the first (if `Conjugate.*:`), or nothing (anything else).
- We don't care about the names (which are the `:`-derived groups), so we `unname` them out.
- It's an list of lists, so we want to combine them, and the easiest is `do.call(c, ..)`.
- Since you want the output to be a `list`, then we `as.list(.)` it.

Comment: How could we have used cumsum  if there were no ":" at the end for number, initial and conjugate

Comment: That sounds like a "recognition" problem, so the regex is your key. Your OP sample data showed that as a clear discriminator. If that's not the case, please update your data to be more representative. (Perhaps just `cumsum(grepl("^(Number|Initial|Conjugate)", vec))`? There needs to be a clear indicator of "new section" or such.)